# Write to the end of each line -autoit

Tags: autoit, filesize, filewriter

Instead of the MsgBox i want the script to read a .txt file and write to the end of each line the result of a variable, in my case is $FileSize

Here is the code for autoit script

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <File.au3>

Test()

Func Test()

    For $i = 1 to _FileCountLines(@TempDir & "\myfiles.txt")
        $mread = FileReadLine(@TempDir & "\myfiles.txt", $i)

    Local $FileSize = FileGetSize($mread)

    MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", ByteSuffix($FileSize)) ;this is just a test
    Next
EndFunc   ;==>Example

Func ByteSuffix($Bytes)
    Local $Index = 0, $aArray = [' bytes', ' KB', ' MB', ' GB', ' TB', ' PB', ' EB', ' ZB', ' YB']
    While $Bytes > 1023
        $Index += 1
        $Bytes /= 1024
    WEnd
    Return Round($Bytes) & $aArray[$Index]
EndFunc
```

Here is the content of .txt file

```
C:\Users\G-PC\Documents\setup.exe
C:\Users\G-PC\Documents\config.ini
C:\Users\G-PC\Documents\image001.jpg
C:\Users\G-PC\Documents\image002.jpg
C:\Users\G-PC\Documents\image003.jpg
```

I want the following result

```
C:\Users\G-PC\Documents\setup.exe [SIZE FOR THIS]
C:\Users\G-PC\Documents\config.ini [SIZE FOR THIS]
C:\Users\G-PC\Documents\image001.jpg [SIZE FOR THIS]
C:\Users\G-PC\Documents\image002.jpg [SIZE FOR THIS]
C:\Users\G-PC\Documents\image003.jpg [SIZE FOR THIS]
```

Comment: I gave you a solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48057487/autoit-get-the-file-size-of-all-files-in-path

Answer (score 2):

There is a [size limit for both string variables and arrays](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/appendix/LimitsDefaults.htm), so you have to process one line at a time when working with big files. This uses a temporary file for output instead of keeping all the information in memory. You can rename (overwriting the original file) the temporary file to the original file name at the end.

```
Func Test()
    Local $InFile = FileOpen(@TempDir & "\myfiles.txt", $FO_READ)
    Local $OutFile = FileOpen(@TempDir & "\myfiles.tmp", $FO_OVERWRITE)
    While True
        $File = FileReadLine($InFile)
        If @error = -1 Then Return ; no more lines to process
        FileWrite($OutFile, $File & " [" & ByteSuffix(FileGetSize($File)) & "]" & @CRLF)
    WEnd
EndFunc   ;==>Test
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sResult = Test()
ConsoleWrite('SIZE LIST' & @CRLF & $sResult)

Func Test()
    Local $FileSize, $sReturn = ''

    For $i = 1 to _FileCountLines(@TempDir & "\myfiles.txt")
        $mread = FileReadLine(@TempDir & "\myfiles.txt", $i)

        $FileSize = FileGetSize($mread)

        ; MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", ByteSuffix($FileSize)) ;this is just a test
        $sReturn &= $mread & " [" & ByteSuffix($FileSize) & "]" & @CRLF
    Next
    Return $sReturn
EndFunc   ;==>Test
```

But a better way instead of reading the text file line by line is the using of _FileReadToArray. Than you can iterate through the array with text lines.

Answer (score 1):

Using line number parameter for `FileReadLine` in a loop resets
the file pointer to the start and scans up to the line number which slows
down the loop as line count increases. Omit that parameter.

Use a file handle so you do not keep on opening and closing
the file with each line read in the loop.

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <File.au3>

$sResult = Test()
MsgBox(0, @ScriptName, $sResult)


Func Test()
    Local $iFileSize, $hFile, $sFilePath, $sResult

    ; Open a file handle to read.
    $hFile = FileOpen(@TempDir & "\myfiles.txt")
    If $hFile = -1 Then
        MsgBox(0x30, @ScriptName, 'Unable to open file to read.')
        Exit 1
    EndIf

    While 1
        ; Read and let AutoIt handle line count.
        $sFilePath = FileReadLine($hFile)
        If @error Then ExitLoop

        $iFileSize = FileGetSize($sFilePath)
        If @error Then ContinueLoop

        $sResult &= StringFormat('%s %s\r\n', $sFilePath, ByteSuffix($iFileSize))
    WEnd

    FileClose($hFile)

    Return $sResult
EndFunc

Func ByteSuffix($Bytes)
    Local $Index = 0
    Local $aArray = [' bytes', ' KB', ' MB', ' GB', ' TB', ' PB', ' EB', ' ZB', ' YB']

    While $Bytes > 1023
        $Index += 1
        $Bytes /= 1024
    WEnd

    Return Round($Bytes) & $aArray[$Index]
EndFunc
```